# Title of navigation bar does not appear

Tags: ios, crossmobile

I have a navigationBar on my Crossmobile application, I want to add Title on it and I'm using the bellow code:

```
navigationController().navigationBar().setBarTintColor(UIColor.colorWithRedGreenBlueAlpha(69.0 / 255.0, 69.0 / 255.0, 69.0 / 255.0, 1.0));
```

I put that code and it does nothing:

```
navigationController().navigationItem().setPrompt("titleTest");
```

I found the navigationItem from documentation of UINavigationBar from https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationbar

has anyone idea how to add the view of the item?

Comment: are you using storyboard or programatically ?

Comment: post your code please

Comment: Just write `self.title = "My Title"` in your vc.

Comment: Hello, no I'm not using storyboard, I will start soon to use it!

Comment: The code is above but the answer is bellow!

Comment: Thank you for self.title = "My Title", but I don't use swift! They told me that was the correct one :D

Comment: Try `navigationItem.title = "Your_Title"` .....It worked for me !

Answer (score 1):

In your view controller's intialization, i.e. in the constructor, you have to do something like:

```java
setTitle("titleTest");
```

Alternatively, you could work on navigationItem and define the title like this:

```java
navigationController().navigationItem().setTitle("titleTest");
```

You don't change the title of the navigation bar directly